# Punctuation after an inline formula

Tags: punctuation, inline

I always wonder if I should put the punctuation after an inline formula inside the formula, like in

```
\(x = 1.\)
```

or outside

```
\(x = 1\).
```

Which is the correct choice, and why?

The related question is about punctuation between formulas, so I think it is slightly different that this.

Comment: If the punctuation is part of the 'surrounding' sentence and not the formula then logically I think it should go outside the `\(...\)`. [If you remove the formula and replace it with syntactically 'equivalent' words, clearly the punctuation should remain.] (I would try to make an analogy with quotation marks here, but in some traditions punctuation marks may be moved inside quotation marks even if strictly speaking the belong to the outside.) That said, I will generally put the closing punctuation mark in a display formula into math mode (i.e. inside `\[...\]`.)

Comment: @moewe yes but if you need to put the punctuation in the display it's best to use `\text{.}` so it uses the font of the surrounding text so it is logically close to putting it outside inline math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside. It is logically part of the sentence structure so the markup is more natural that way, and it ensures that you get the same font as other sentence ending full stops, which may or may not be the case if you use the math `.`

Comment: Can we be sure that there is no line break between the formula and the punctuation? I see that sometimes in mathjax markup it happens

Comment: TeX will never break a line at that position @enzotib

Comment: If the math is in a display, the punctuation must be included in the display; otherwise it will, by definition, be placed on the next line.  (I'm assuming you were ignoring that possibility.)

Comment: Also keep in mind that the comma used in math font may differ from the comma used in text font; Euler and Concrete font may serve as an example.  Hence one should write \[<some formula>\text{,}\] ...

Comment: @barbarabeeton yes I mention that in comments under the question but the title is explicitly about inline math